# Uploading certain file types to server through Dropzone.js

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, dropzone.js

I'm trying to upload Microsoft Access-files to my webserver, using dropzone.js. Most files seem to upload fine: My action is called, and the files end up in the right folder. But if I try to send for example .mdb (MS Access) or .pdf files, the action isn't even called, and dropzone reports that server responded with 0 code.

I do not use any `acceptedFiles` or `acceptedMimeTypes` options in dropzone, and as far as I know, leaving them out should make it accept any filetypes. Also, if I restrict a file type, it does give me a proper message that the file type is not allowed.

HTML:

```
<div id="dropzone">
    <form action="/Synchronizations/Upload" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone"
        id="myAwesomeDropzone">
    </form>
</div>
```

Javascript looks like:

```
    <link href="/Content/css/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/dropzone.js"></script>
    <script>
        Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
            paramName: "file", 
            maxFilesize: 200
        };
    </script>
```

The action looks like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file)
    {
        foreach (var f in file)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(f.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), fileName);
            f.SaveAs(path);
        } 
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you hitting a file size limitation?  Perhaps look at this: http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-07-15/upload-large-files-asp-net-radasyncupload